# Question of Kronecker Product

Tags: tensor-products

The following is from a paper:

[image]

---

Question:

The G should be a (k,n) matrix. However, the kron(ei,ej) should be a (n×n,1) vector. So
the resulting G should be a (n×n,1) vector. Is anything wrong or it is not a kronecker
product?

Note: (k,n) matrix means k-rows, n-columns matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. For column vectors $e_i$ and $e_j$, we can write the Kronecker product as $e_i\otimes e_j=e_ie_j^T$, where $e_j^T$ denotes the transpose of $e_j$. Thus, it will be a $n\times n$ matrix.

I'm assuming there is something with the $g_{ij}$ that reduce the rank of the matrix $G$ to make the image of its output in $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: Thanks! It seems Kronecker product can have two forms; I do not know the form of outer product